# Select filter an alphanumeric column by the dates it contains

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` and I want to get the rows where column `Election` is equal to a specific year.

```
Unnamed: 0  Map Level   Precinct ID Precinct Name   Election    Invalid Ballots (%) More Ballots Than Votes (#) More Votes Than Ballots (#) Total Voter Turnout (#) Total Voter Turnout (%) ... Average votes per minute (17:00-20:00)  CDM ED  FG  GD  LP  NR  UNM Results others
0   0   Precinct    1   63-1    2008 Parliamentary 0.0  0.0 0.0 749 62.11   ... 1.01    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 77.17   United National Movement    22.83
1   1   Precinct    10  63-10   2008 Parliamentary 0.0  0.0 0.0 419 70.42   ... 0.61    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 71.12   United National Movement    28.87
...
136 159 Precinct    8   63-1    2013 Presidential   1.75    0.0 0.0 506 50.75   ... 0.52    2.96    0.20    0.00    0.00    1.19    0.00    0.00    Giorgi Margvelashvili   95.65
137 160 Precinct    9   63-10   2013 Presidential   2.50    0.0 0.0 625 48.04   ... 0.66    1.92    0.80    0.00    0.00    1.60    0.00    0.00    Giorgi Margvelashvili   95.68
```

Let say I want the 2008 election. So I did the following function :

```
def results_precinct_election(precinct,election_year):
    df['Election'] = df['Election'].astype(int)
    df_election = df.loc[df['Election'] == election_year]
    x = df_election[["Christian-Democratic Movement","European Democrats","Free Georgia","Georgian Dream","Labour Party","New Right","United National Movement","others"]]
```

But I received :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-203-317aa5d54b6d> in <module>
----> 1 x = results_precinct_election("63-1", 2008)
      2 y = results_precinct_election("63-1", 2013)
      3 random.seed(0)
      4 beta = estimate_beta()

<ipython-input-202-1cd2d166f35a> in results_precinct_election(precinct, election)
      1 # I want a line of a given precinct for a given election
      2 def results_precinct_election(precinct,election):
----> 3     df['Election'] = df['Election'].astype(int)
      4     df_election = df.loc[df['Election'] == election and df['Precinct Name'] == precinct]
      5     x = df_election[["Christian-Democratic Movement","European Democrats","Free Georgia","Georgian Dream","Labour Party","New Right","United National Movement","others"]]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, **kwargs)
   5689             # else, only a single dtype is given
   5690             new_data = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors,
-> 5691                                          **kwargs)
   5692             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)
   5693 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in astype(self, dtype, **kwargs)
    529 
    530     def astype(self, dtype, **kwargs):
--> 531         return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
    532 
    533     def convert(self, **kwargs):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in apply(self, f, axes, filter, do_integrity_check, consolidate, **kwargs)
    393                                             copy=align_copy)
    394 
--> 395             applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    396             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    397 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, **kwargs)
    532     def astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None, **kwargs):
    533         return self._astype(dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors, values=values,
--> 534                             **kwargs)
    535 
    536     def _astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in _astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, **kwargs)
    631 
    632                     # _astype_nansafe works fine with 1-d only
--> 633                     values = astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
    634 
    635                 # TODO(extension)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    681         # work around NumPy brokenness, #1987
    682         if np.issubdtype(dtype.type, np.integer):
--> 683             return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)
    684 
    685         # if we have a datetime/timedelta array of objects

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe()

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2008 Parliamentary - Majoritarian'
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is column contains some non numeric values.

Posible solutions is convert them to `NaN`s:

```
df['Election'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Election'], errors='coerce')
```

Or extract years - numbers, but if not exist are return again missing values:

```
df['Election'] = df['Election'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
```